# htaccess redirect subfolder to subdomain without changing url

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to redirect to the url `localhost/anno` to `localhost/tut/anno`

I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847256/htaccess-redirect-domain-to-subdirectory-without-changing-url)

and wrote this `.htaccess` rule

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?localhost\anno$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^localhost/ /tut/anno%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

But still i am getting 404 error.

What is the wrong i my rule ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^anno/(.*)$ /tut/anno/$1 [NC,L]
```

This internally redirects "/anno/foo" to "/tut/anno/foo"

EDIT

you need to Reorder your rules  like this :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^anno/(.*)$ /tut/annotorious/$1 [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, it works when i have like [yours](https://eval.in/428634) but does not works, if i have like [this](https://eval.in/428635) ....