# how to I redirect a domain using the index.html file?

Tags: html, indexing

I have two domain names but I have each domain name directing to the same IP. How could I redirect each domain to the correct place using the index.html file? Below is some pseudo code:

```
if web adddress= http://siteA.com forward too http://siteA.com/siteA_Dir
if web address = http://SiteB.com forward too http://siteB.com/siteB_Dir
else go to localhost:80
```

I do not want to use a htaccess file as I have not made one. I currently have this code in my index.html file:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://siteA/SiteA_Dir" />
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess redirect domain to subdirectory without changing URL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847256/htaccess-redirect-domain-to-subdirectory-without-changing-url)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this in javascript:

```
<script>

var domain = window.location.href;

domain = domain.replace('http://', '');
domain = domain.replace('.com/', '');
domain = domain.replace('.com', '');

switch (domain) {
    case 'siteA': window.location.href = 'http://siteA.com/siteA_Dir'; break;
    case 'siteB': window.location.href = 'http://siteB.com/siteB_Dir'; break;
    default: window.location.href = 'http://127.0.0.1/';
}

</script>
```

Comment: What if the url was http:// www. siteA.com/? or, "https:// www. siteA.com/http:// .com/"?

Comment: This code worked a treat

Comment: You're most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to have this logic in pure HTML, though a small javascript snippet should suffice

```
<script>
  (function(loc) {
    if (loc.indexOf('http://siteA.com/') === 0) {
        window.location = 'http://siteA.com/siteA_dir';
    }
    else if (loc.indexOf('http://siteB.com/') === 0) {
        window.location = 'http://siteB.com/siteB_dir';
    }
    else {
        window.location = 'http://localhost:80';
    }
  })(window.location);
</script>
```

Comment: What if the URL started with "www."?

Comment: then it can be easily added to the list. the code merely shows a solution, if OP wanted a clever solution in client javascript capable of doing all kinds of nifty redirects, it would have said so in the question. None of us included any request parameters and/or anchor preservation either as this wasn't part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JS:

```js
    var currUrl = window.location.href;
    var urlbase = currUrl.replace("https://www.","");
    var urlbase = urlbase.replace("http://www.","");
    var urlbase = urlbase.replace("https://","");
    var urlbase = urlbase.replace("http://","");
    var urlbase = urlbase.substr(0,9);

    switch(urlbase) {
      case "siteA.com":
        document.write("site A: " + urlbase);
        break;
      case "siteB.com":
        document.write("site B: " + urlbase);
        break;
      default:
        document.write("N/A: " + urlbase);
        break;
    }
```

Comment: I can see why you asked "how about urls starting with 'www'?", as you cleverly thought of that. Now let me ask you some questions: how does your code redirect? Why do you redeclare the same `urlbase` var over and over again? And finally, why didn't you use a single `.replace(/^https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?/, '')`? I'm not looking for answers to these questions, it just struck me as odd that you asked the same question on two answers, which - to me - seemed you wanted to point out your cleverness, so I thought to return the favour ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Rename index.html" to "index.php"

Add this code to your file

```
<?php 
$CurrentUrl='http://'. $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; 
  if ($CurrentUrl=="http://siteA.com")
  echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV ='Refresh' Content ='0; URL =http://siteA /SiteA_Dir'>";

   elseif ($CurrentUrl=="http://siteB.com")
     echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV ='Refresh' Content ='0; URL =http://siteB/SiteB_Dir'>";

  else
     echo "<META HTTP-EQUIV ='Refresh' Content ='0; URL =http://localhost'>";

?>
```