# Using .htaccess to point primary domain to subfolder without altering the URL

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, shared-hosting

I have a domain i.e www.domain.org and want to point it to a subfolder on my server. The main domain loads from /public_html and now, I want to load the domain from /public_html/domain2017.

I have researched various solutions on the web, but all I get is a redirect.
The redirect is not preferred because I end up with www.domain.org/domain2017 when I want to stay as www.domain.org but load the index.php file of www.domain.org/domain2017. Hopefully, this makes sense. Note: I have a WordPress installation within public_html/domain2017.

Below is example content of my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.org$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^subdir/ /domain2017%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
</IfModule>
```

[Solution Attempt 1](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/htaccess/redirect-without-changing-url) [Solution Attempt 2](https://my.bluehost.com/cgi/help/347) [Solution Attempt 3](http://www.zymphonies.com/blog/how-redirect-domain-subdirectory-without-changing-url) [Solution Attempt 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847256/htaccess-redirect-domain-to-subdirectory-without-changing-url)

I have tried all of the above links and they simply redirect my domain to the URL and does not prevent the URL in the address bar from changing

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yourdomain.com$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.yourdomain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public_html/domain2017/
RewriteRule (.*) /public_html/domain2017/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I get the following error

Not Found
The requested URL /public_html/.....2017/ was not found on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.